# Java poi Excel insert picture, the picture blocking the left and top borders of the cell

Tags: java

I used poi to insert a picture for Excel. The picture will always be pressed, blocking the left and top borders of the cell. Please tell me how I can fix it.

[Excel picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmlCK.jpg):

```
ClientAnchor anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, (short) cell.getColumnIndex(), cell.getRow().getRowNum(), (short) (cell.getColumnIndex() + 1), cell.getRow().getRowNum() + 1);
anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);
byte[] data = ImageUtils.getImage(imagePath);
getDrawingPatriarch(cell.getSheet()).createPicture(anchor,cell.getSheet().getWorkbook().addPicture(data, getImageType(data)));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can attempt to either revise the size of the image you have, or revise the size of the cell to solve this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).